# VBA Loop that removes punctuation from a given range

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am pretty new to VBA, and i need to make a loop that removes certain punctuation which is referenced as values A2:A33 on my spreadsheet, from a string. This is what I have so far, struggling with the replace function. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

```
Function CleanDescription(rawDescription As String) As String
Dim punctuationRng As Range
Set punctuationRng = Worksheets("ToRemove").Range("A2:A33")

Dim cleanDesc As String
cleanDesc = rawDescription

For i = 1 To punctuationRng.Count
cleanDesc = Replace(cleanDesc, punctuationRng, "")
Next i

CleanDescription = cleanDesc
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `For Each Loop` as shown below

```
Function CleanDescription(rawDescription As String) As String
    Dim punctuationRng As Range
    Set punctuationRng = Worksheets("ToRemove").Range("A2:A33")

    Dim cleanDesc As String
    cleanDesc = rawDescription

    Dim aCell As Range

    For Each aCell In punctuationRng
        cleanDesc = Replace(cleanDesc, aCell.Value2, "")
    Next aCell

    CleanDescription = cleanDesc
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can achieve substituting each value in a range of cells that is present in a string by a `For Each`:**

```
Function CleanDescription(rawDescription As String) As String
Dim punctuationRng As Range
Set punctuationRng = Worksheets("ToRemove").Range("A2:A33")

Dim cleanDesc As String
cleanDesc = rawDescription

For Each punctuationCell In punctuationRng
    cleanDesc = Replace(cleanDesc, punctuationCell.Value, "")
Next punctuationCell

CleanDescription = cleanDesc
End Function
```

If you don't like the For Each you could also achieve it with a `For Loop`:

```
Dim cellValue As String
For r = 1 to punctuationRng.Rows.Count
    For c = 1 to punctuationRng.Columns.Count
        cellValue = punctuationRng.cells(r, c).Value
        cleanDesc = Replace(cleanDesc, cellValue, "")
    Next c
Next r
```

Comment: If I have sunderstood the question correctly then `punctuationRng` is not where the replacing needs to be done. It contains the strings which needs to be replaced in `rawDescription` :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout correct, I misunderstood the question - just updated my answer